# Android Studio: of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I get error: of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray when I try to retrieve JSON values.

```
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++){


            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(i);
            String id       = JO.getString("languages");

            dataParsed = dataParsed + id;

        }
```

The JSON looks like this (have removed sensitive data)

```
   {  
   "ip":"",
   "type":"",
   "continent_code":"EU",
   "continent_name":"Europe",
   "country_code":"GB",
   "country_name":"United Kingdom",
   "region_code":"ENG",
   "region_name":"England",
   "city":"",
   "zip":"",
   "latitude":,
   "longitude":,
   "location":{  
      "geoname_id":,
      "capital":"London",
      "languages":[  
         {  
            "code":"en",
            "name":"English",
            "native":"English"
         }
      ],
      "country_flag":"http:\/\/assets.ipstack.com\/flags\/gb.svg",
      "country_flag_emoji":"\ud83c\uddec\ud83c\udde7",
      "country_flag_emoji_unicode":"U+1F1EC U+1F1E7",
      "calling_code":"44",
      "is_eu":true
   }
}
```

I should mention that the data I actually want to retrieve is the name of the language.

Comment: please post well-formatted JSON

Comment: Done. Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject objLocation = obj.getJSONObject("location");
JSONArray arrayLanguage = objLocation.getJSONArray("languages");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayLanguage.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) arrayLanguage.get(i);
    String id = JO.getString("languages");
    dataParsed = dataParsed + id;
}
```